# How come we never saw Dragons leaving the body of the Dragon Slayers in Fairy Tail (2014)?

Tags: anime-production, fairy-tail

We don't see the Dragons leaving the body of the Dragon Slayers except in Natsu's case, even though Igneel mentioned it in Episode 89. Why is that? Did they forget to animate it?

[Edit- Note :If they have not mentioned it in manga then wouldn't that will be a plot hole because everybody will be aware of the dragons leaving the dragon slayers body and no one would have been surprised to see the face getting destroyed at that time. Also fighting Achnologia would have been much easier.]

Comment: What event are you referring to? Can you cite an episode and scene for context?

Comment: ep-89. Igneel mentioned all the dragons where residing in the dragon slayers body. But so far i've seen only igneel coming out of natsu.

Comment: I couldnt find why you put it on hold though i asked a clear cut question , which by the way you will only understand if you have watched the anime so far. I have included the ep no.  @ ʞɹɐzǝɹ♦

Comment: @Reaching-Out Yup, clear question to me.

Comment: IIRC It wasn't shown in the manga either, so there is no reason for them to show it in the anime.

Comment: I have edited my question now.. @Ayase Eri

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all Dragons of 1st and 3rd generations Dragon Slayers had shown themselves in the anime. Igneel againts Acnologia, while the other 4 (Metallicana, Grandine, Weisslogia, Skiadrum) helped in destroying Face.

Comment: Can you cite sources supporting your answer? As it is, your post is short and sounds speculative

Answer (score -1):

If I remember it correctly, I think it was showed between the last four episodes(86-90) of Fairy Tail (2014).

A link stating that their dragons help them - http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_263

> However, his celebration is cut short as the Dragon King crashes down near them, the Fire Dragon King holding him down with one claw and encouraging the humans not to give up hope. The ones who help humanity in this dire predicament are none other than the guardian Dragons of Wendy, Rogue, Gajeel and Sting, the powerful beasts easily demolishing the seemingly indestructible pillars by flying through them at great speeds.